# Jasper report preview shows data in field but while generating report through java it prints NULL

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Jasperreport successfully generated (JAsperTest.pdf ) with below exception but It didn't print any integer values in ID field. It prints only NULL in ID field. But preview in jasper tool shows all integer values in ID field and not in report generated through java code.

```
"PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer determinePatchedItext
WARNING: Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering"
```

This question was asked in other forum but no solution found. Please help me with the solution. I tried removing itext5.5.0 jar to itext 7 jar but which resulted in error.

Jar files included in lib folder : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYMCt.jpg

JasperTest.java

```
import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
    public class JasperClass {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException {

            // Compile jrxml file.
           JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                   .compileReport("C:/repo/JasperTest/Jaspertest.jrxml");

           // Parameters for report
           Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

           // DataSource
           // This is simple example, no database.
           // then using empty datasource.
           JRDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();

           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                   parameters, dataSource);


           // Make sure the output directory exists.
           File outDir = new File("C:/repo/JasperTest");
           outDir.mkdirs();

           // Export to PDF.
           JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                   "C:/repo/JasperTest/Jaspertest.pdf");

           System.out.println("Done!");
       }
    }
```

JasperTest.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Jaspertest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="98c6f0de-1e25-4ff3-b982-cfa45f54b507">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value="Y2l0eSAsMTUsMTUsMTFlZThiNTgtMzM2OC00ZmQ3LWEzOTYtY2ZhMTM4MzllMjZhOw=="/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Dataadaptertest.xml"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID
FROM city]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <group name="ID">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="fe0a9fb7-deef-4393-a835-7cf9e41b8bef"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Test Successfull]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="63" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="89" y="33" width="100" height="30" uuid="c2a5e228-a3f1-42fc-8064-688191cb7633"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="46" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="89" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="126f1743-5bae-4e84-8bc6-9b36c2a808cc"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Any update on above would be more helpful.

Comment: 1) You should post the list of project's libraries at text, not as image; 2) Your image is worng - it contains javaflow lib (looks like you removed this lib); 3) This is a warning, not an error; 4) Did you try to export report in another output format (doc or xls or rtf)? Is everything fine?; 5) Did you try to use different fonts?; 6) What is `jasper tool`? Jaspersoft Studio?

Comment: You are passing `JREmptyDataSource` at your code - your report should be empty

Comment: Used JAR in lib folder:
`commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
groovy-all-1.0- beta-10.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
itext-pdfa-5.5.0.jar
itextpdf-5.5.4.jar
jasperreports-fonts-6.2.0
mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar`

Tried fonts:
`jasperreports-fonts-4.0.1
jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0
jasperreports-fonts-6.4.0`
Tried itext:
`Itext7 -pdfa-7.0.2.jar
itextpdf-5.5.9.jar`

When I tried to export to Doc. The export is successful without warning but still, the field is NULL. But in the preview, it shows the value.

Comment: 1) You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46687711/edit) post; 2)  You are passing `JREmptyDataSource` at your code - your report should be empty

Comment: I did a JDBC Mysql connection with Jasperstudio and tried to generate pdf from java. With JREmptyDataSource in code, the report generated with Static text data. But the value not printed which was called from SQL.  What kind of changes should I need to make in Java code to run the .jrxml file along with value.  Any link similar to this issue would be helpful @AlexK.

Comment: You need to pass connection, not a datasource

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED. Now I could see data in my report. I made a Connection to SQL as said by Alex. Thank you.  I am pasting Code below for reference.
avaCallJasperReport.java.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.ExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.OutputStreamExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimplePdfExporterConfiguration;

import conn.ConnectionUtils;

public class avaCallJasperReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException,
            ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String reportSrcFile = "C:/repo/JasperTest/Jaspertest.jrxml";

        // First, compile jrxml file.
        JasperReport jasperReport =    JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSrcFile);

        Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

        // Parameters for report
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                parameters, conn);

        // Make sure the output directory exists.
        File outDir = new File("C:/repo/JasperTest");
        outDir.mkdirs();

        // PDF Exportor.
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        ExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(print);
        // ExporterInput
        exporter.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

        // ExporterOutput
        OutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(
                "C:/repo/JasperTest/FirstJasperReport.pdf");
        // Output
        exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);

        //
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();

        System.out.print("tttt!");
    }
}
```

MySQLconnUtils.Java

```
package conn;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class MySQLconnUtils {



        public static Connection getMySQLConnection()
                throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            String hostName = "localhost";
            String dbName = "world";
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "root";
            return getMySQLConnection(hostName, dbName, userName, password);
        }

        public static Connection getMySQLConnection(String hostName, String dbName,
                String userName, String password) throws SQLException,
                ClassNotFoundException {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Get qq ... ");
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostName + ":3306/" + dbName;

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName,
                    password);
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

ConnectionUtils.Java

```
package conn;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionUtils {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {

        // Using Oracle
        // You may be replaced by other Database.
        return MySQLconnUtils.getMySQLConnection();
    }

    //
    // Test Connection ...
    //
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Get connection ... ");

        // Get a Connection object
        Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

        System.out.println("Get connection " + conn);

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```